# Finding recepients to whom the email subscription failed in SSRS

Tags: email, reporting-services, subscription

I needed to send customized emails using data in our database.We created a subscription on a dummy report to configure sending emails through SSRS.
After the subscription ran, we could see some 800 records failed from 1900 cases.We know the count but how can we know to whom email was fired successfully and for whom it failed so that we resend emails only to specific people.

I checked ExecutionLog and Subscription table from ReportServer DB but that gives generic information about the sunscription run and not list of failed recepients.

I could not find this info in SSRS log as well on server.

Is there any way of configuration so that we can get this information.

Comment: is this a data driven subscription with 1900 email addresses coming from the db ?

Comment: Yes..email plus information specific to each user.